# How to export previous Firebase Analytics to Bigquery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

Recently I linked Firebase analytics with BigQuery.  But I realized that only new data can be queried. I wanted to reach Firebase analytics data of the last 2 months. Normally they can be viewed in Firebase but I could not export them to BigQuery.

Is there any way of exporting those previous data? I need them on BigQuery.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 3):

Analytics events will only be exported from the moment you connect Firebase Analytics to BigQuery. There is no way to export events that occurred before you connected Firebase Analytics to BigQuery.